# Ionic Capacitor Android: Deep links work in other apps but not in Chrome

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deep-linking, capacitor

I'm trying to set up deep links with Ionic Capacitor, I've done this before without any problems for other apps however I'm currently struggling with getting it to work.

I've set up `intent-filter` in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="reporter.ironeko.com" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I have generated and added the json from [Google's page](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator). Testing it also tells me it's been set up correctly.

[image]

In my Android emulator, if I try to click the link from the Messages app, it works.

[image]

But in Chrome, clicking a link with the same address opens a web page.

[image]

Did I forget something? Is this possibly a cache issue?

Any ideas?

EDIT:

So I did some more testing, it looks like deep linking doesn't work if the domain you're currently on is the same as the one you're trying to deep link to.

Is there any way to work around this?